# Transfer control between two UIPanGestureRecognizer without lifting finger

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a `WKWebView` and a header above it that I would like to scroll away when the user pans the scroll view (similar to how Google Chrome/Safari work).

I've added my own pan gesture on top of the `WKWebView` so I can capture touches and prevent `WKWebView`'s `scrollView` from scrolling by resetting the `contentOffset` each time the user pans while the header is visible.

I would like to be able to turn on and off the builtin `scrollView`'s `panGestureRecognizer` while continuously panning.

Is there a way I can enable/disable pan gestures and have they respond without restarting the pan gesture?

Comment: you can have them recognize simultaneously. Will that help?

Comment: That lets me trigger both at the same time but even with that one there doesn't seem to be a way to turn on/off one of the gestures while I'm performing the gesture.